# How can I select the best fan blade for my application

Tags: fluid-dynamics, air

I am working to build a large 12v fan with the goal of generating the strongest "breeze" possible.

I began with a radiator fan pulled from a car, and quickly learned that while this particular fan can move lots of air, it generates essentially no "breeze". The air coming out the back of the fan is completely unfocused and only a short distance from the fan (~2 meters) the airflow is basically imperceptible.

For the sake of this question, I want to define the breeze as a strong, focused flow of air that moves straight out from the centre of the fan, which increases or decreases in strength as you move closer/further from the fan.

Additionally, please assume that power is not an issue here, I have more power than I need, and am only interested in generating the best "breeze" possible.

I am assuming I want the largest diameter fan size available in whichever style would provide the best "breeze", but certainly open to being corrected on that point.

I am looking at a number of different designs available as replacement blades for household cooling fans, but I'm hesitant to clutter this question with descriptions of those options, if anyone thinks they would be helpful/relevant let me know in the comments.

I am interested in understanding overall what factors dictate how focused and strong the breeze leaving the fan will be.

I'm also interested in what (if any) role the fan housing will play in this.

Comment: whoops, I've re-posted on the engineering stack exchange. Thanks.